# Can i create a Customized reporting in CitrusFramework

Tags: citrus-framework

My Current project i have used a Extent Reporting"http://extentreports.com/".
Is there a way where i can read the Summary Report of Citrus and Print it into Extent Report Format.

Attached Sample Report for Citrus Framework,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgkFu.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Citrus provides several reporting and listener interfaces that get informed about test state such as success or failure. You can add custom implementations of these interfaces to the Spring application context. The custom reporting class may then create Extent reports via Java API.

The listener interfaces are located in [com.consol.citrus.report](https://github.com/christophd/citrus/tree/master/modules/citrus-core/src/main/java/com/consol/citrus/report) package: MessageListener, TestSuiteListener, TestListener, TestActionListener, TestReporter

You can have a look at the default [LoggingReporter](https://github.com/christophd/citrus/blob/master/modules/citrus-core/src/main/java/com/consol/citrus/report/LoggingReporter.java) as a sample implementation.

Comment: Thanks Chris, It Helped on Finding a Solution.

Comment: Glad that I could help out! How about accepting the answer then?